# How to pause d3.js simulation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following is the code for simulating a force directed graph using d3.js

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(graphWidth / 2, height / 2))
  .force("x", d3.forceX(graphWidth / 2).strength(0.1))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.1))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(radius + 10))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().strength(1).id(function (d) {
    return d._id;
  }))
  .alphaTarget(0)
  .alphaDecay(0.05)
```

The above code works fine.

But is there a way to temporarily pause simulation while dragging a node?

Here is the code for dragging.

```
function dragstarted(ev) {
  if (!ev.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  ev.subject.fx = transform.invertX(ev.x);
  ev.subject.fy = transform.invertY(ev.y);
}
```

But when I add this then dragging is disabled.

```
function dragstarted(ev) {
  simulation.stop()
  if (!ev.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  ev.subject.fx = transform.invertX(ev.x);
  ev.subject.fy = transform.invertY(ev.y);
}
```

Is there a way to temporarily pause the simulation while dragging a node?

Comment: So you want to pin all other nodes in place while you drag one?

Comment: yes. and pause simulation while dragging... and continue there after...

Comment: What do you mean by "pause simulation"?

Comment: Currently when I drag the node it is moving other nodes also... so the idea is that I want to initially arrange things using simulation.... later after the simulation/ arrangement have completed I want to have a pause to simulation... or pause/stop the simulation temporarily  when I drag a node...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by overriding all forces whenever you start dragging and pin every non-dragged node in place using a strong force for that position only.

```js
const graph = {
  nodes: [{
      name: 'john',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'simon',
      age: 37
    },
    {
      name: 'manjoor',
      age: 35
    },
    {
      name: 'lorg',
      age: 34
    },
    {
      name: 'kilvin',
      age: 32
    },
  ],
  links: [{
      source: 'john',
      target: 'simon'
    },
    {
      source: 'john',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
    {
      source: 'simon',
      target: 'lorg'
    },
    {
      source: 'simon',
      target: 'kilvin'
    },
    {
      source: 'manjoor',
      target: 'kilvin'
    },
    {
      source: 'lorg',
      target: 'john'
    },
    {
      source: 'lorg',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
    {
      source: 'kilvin',
      target: 'manjoor'
    },
  ]
}


const canvas = d3.select('#network')

const width = canvas.attr('width')
const height = canvas.attr('height')
const r = 30
const ctx = canvas.node().getContext('2d')

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeAccent);

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .on('tick', update)

function pinNodes() {
  simulation
    .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x).strength(d => d.fx === undefined ? 10 : 0))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y).strength(d => d.fx === undefined ? 10 : 0))
    .force('collide', null)
    .force('charge', null)
    .force('link', null)
}

function unpinNodes() {
  simulation
    .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
    .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(r + 20))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
    .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(node => node.name))
}

unpinNodes();
simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
simulation.force('link').links(graph.links)

canvas.call(d3.drag()
  .container(canvas.node())
  .subject(dragsubject)
  .on('start', dragstarted)
  .on('drag', dragged)
  .on('end', dragended)
)

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
  graph.links.forEach(drawLink)
  ctx.stroke()

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1
  graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode)
  ctx.fill()
}

function dragsubject(event) {
  return simulation.find(event.x, event.y, r);
}

function drawNode(d) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color(d.party)
  ctx.moveTo(d.x, d.y)
  ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
}

function drawLink(l) {
  ctx.moveTo(l.source.x, l.source.y)
  ctx.lineTo(l.target.x, l.target.y)
}

function dragstarted(event) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
  event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
  pinNodes()
}

function dragged(event) {
  event.subject.fx = event.x;
  event.subject.fy = event.y;
}

function dragended(event) {
  unpinNodes();
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  event.subject.fx = null;
  event.subject.fy = null;
}

update()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.js"></script>
<canvas id="network" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```